# Why does my IIS App pool show .NET CLR version and not .NET Framework version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have recently upgraded to a Windows 10 laptop and I've attempted to move my projects to Visual Studio 2015.

However when I do debugging in IIS it does not work.  I have published a project to IIS directly but none of the .NET code is processed.  I end up with the script tags showing on the browsed page, but no errors.

I have looked for days and I see that the App pool shows ".NET CLR version" and not ".NET Framework Version"  on the drop down.

Could this be the issue that .NET code is not running and if so, how can I get the .NET Framework option/installed and showing?   I have gone through the process of installing via the Windows add remove components.

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is an XY problem. Just run aspnet_regiis...

Comment: Please go to learn what is CLR and what is .NET Framework. It must show CLR here.

Comment: [.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Codecaster I have run aspnet_regiis no luck

Comment: @Lex Li  but it isnt always CLR, sometimes it is .net Framework that appears

Comment: @Randir because initially the developers of IIS failed to seriously choose the correct terms. What you see recently is the revised version. Even Microsoft makes mistakes and you should be aware of that.

Comment: FYI - I eventually got it to work after reinstalling .Net two more times.  Thank you

Comment: @Rand Happy it worked for you, but the Root cause, why you saw the .Net CLR but not .Net Framework in the Application Pool, is there any option to add or remove columns?